# Statusbar Colors iOS7 iPad WebApp

Tags: ipad, web-applications, ios7, fullscreen, statusbar

I've got an iPad WebApp with a white Background. When launching it in fullscreen mode, the iOS statusbar is fully transparent, so its white. Problem is, the Text on it is also white. So you can't read a thing in that statusbar (except for the batteryicon, because its green inside).

Is there any way to change the statusbars' textcolor (eg to black)?

Answer (score 0):

In yourapp-Info.plist add:

```
Status bar is initally hidden: NO
Status bar style: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque (for black text color)
View controller-based status bar appearence: NO
```

Comment: sorry, have you tried `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">` for oldschool black bar or `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`? , but keep in mind that the bar meta tags are pretty buggy in iOS7!